# $V = \operatorname{Im} T \oplus \operatorname{Im}T^t \oplus H$ where $T^2 = 0$ and $H = \ker T \cap \ker T^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be a square matrix regarded as a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that $T^2 = 0$. Let $H =  \ker T \cap \ker T^t$. Show that $V = \operatorname{Im} T \oplus \operatorname{Im}T^t \oplus H$.

---

**[my proof]**

If $T = 0$, $V = \operatorname{Im} T \oplus \operatorname{Im}T^t \oplus H = \{0\} \oplus \{0\} \oplus V = V$

If $T \neq 0$, $V = \ker T\cup \ker T^t$ by rank-nullity theorem (* But I am still confusing how the rank-nullity theorem proves this)

and we know $\operatorname{Im} T\subseteq \ker T$ and $\operatorname{Im} T^t\subseteq \ker T^t$ from $T^2 =0$.

Now we need to prove that $\ker T \setminus \operatorname{Im} T = \emptyset$ and $\ker T^t\setminus \operatorname{Im} T^t = \emptyset$ to finish the proof, but can't know how to prove it.

Any hint?

Comment: Something like 
(0 1 \\ 0 0)
Satisfies T^2 = 0 but T is not zero.  Does that help?

Comment: Any such operator such that $T\neq 0$ but $T^2=0$ will be such that $\emptyset \subsetneq \text{Image}(T)\subseteq \ker(T)$.  Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional as well, the rank-nullity theorem will imply even more.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's what I wanted to know.. thx.. but how to prove that property?

Comment: Remember what it means to be in the image of an operator.  Next, notice that $Tv\in \text{Image}(T)$ for every $v$ and notice that $T(Tv)=T^2v=0v=0$.  Now., formalize each of these observations and word the appropriate conclusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz you just proved it. thx. Any hint for me to proceed further to deal with $H$? What kind of the set $H$ would imply to show that entire vector space would be seperated into different those 3 sets?

Comment: examples such as $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, would help but to also  see that $T^n \in Ker(T) \forall n \geq 2$ as $T^2  =0$!

Comment: Suppose $v\in V$.  We wish to prove that $v\in \text{Im}(T)\oplus \text{Im}(T^t)\oplus H$.  Now... consider using projections and write $v=v_a+v_b+v_c$ where $v_a\in \text{Im}(T)$, $v_b\in\text{Im}(T^t)$, and $v_c\in H$.  You may have to be a bit clever in how you actually accomplish that and in showing that it is actually allowed in the first place.

Comment: @BAYMAX thx. it was obvious but I was missing

Comment: @JMoravitz what do you mena by "using projections"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra).  It should be clear that we can at least write $v=v_a+(v-v_a)$ for the first step.  It becomes harder to see why we can continue with what is left over and why this is unambiguous.

Comment: @JMoravitz is there any guarantees that $KerT\cup KerT^t = V$? to see those three makes the whole, I need to first specify what makes the V as a whole.

Comment: perhaps that's the rank-nullity theorem right!

Comment: @BAYMAX Which one do you refer to with "that"?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to $V= Ker(T) \cup Ker(T^t)$ and before it becomes a long chat here, I would just say that there is a chat room dedicated to Linear algebra like [Linear algebra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13473/linear-abstract-algebra).

Comment: @BAYMAX if I assume $KerT \cup KerT^t=V$ one thing that is left on me is about how to show $KerT \setminus ImT \cup KerT^t\setminus ImT^t \in H$ How can we get to this conclusion?

Comment: edited OP to finalize the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{Im} T^t \,\dot+\, \ker T = V$. Firstly, the sum is direct (i.e. intersection is trivial):

$$T^tx \in \operatorname{Im}T^t \cap \ker T \implies TT^tx = 0 \implies (T^tx)^t(T^tx) = x^tTT^tx = 0 \implies T^tx = 0$$

and secondly, $\dim\operatorname{Im} T^t + \dim\ker T = \dim\operatorname{Im} T + \dim\ker T = \dim V$, by the rank-nullity theorem.

Now, as you stated, $T^2 = 0$ implies that $\operatorname{Im} T \subseteq \ker T$ and $\operatorname{Im} T^t \subseteq \ker T^t$

$$V = \operatorname{Im} T^t \,\dot+\, \ker T \subseteq \ker T^t \,\dot+\, \ker T$$
so $\ker T^t \,\dot+\, \ker T = V$.

Now we claim that $V = \operatorname{Im} T \,\dot+\, \operatorname{Im} T^t \,\dot+ \,H$.

Firstly, the sum is direct. Assume that $0 = Tx + T^ty + z$ with $x,y \in V, z \in H$. Applying $T$ and $T^t$ gives

$$0 = T^2x + TT^t + Tz = TT^ty \implies (T^ty)^tT^ty = y^tTT^ty = 0 \implies T^ty = 0$$
$$0 = T^tTx + (T^t)^2z + Tz = TT^ty \implies (Tx)^t(Tx) = x^tT^tTx = 0 \implies Tx =0$$

and thus also $z = 0$.

Secondly, we have:

\begin{align}
\dim H &= \dim (\ker T \cap \ker T^t) \\
&= \dim\ker T + \dim\ker T^t - \dim(\ker T\,\dot+\, \ker T^t) \\
&= \dim\ker T + \dim\ker T^t - \dim V
\end{align}

so 
\begin{align}
\dim\operatorname{Im} T  + \dim \operatorname{Im} T^t + \dim H  &= \dim\operatorname{Im} T  + \dim \operatorname{Im} T^t +
 \dim\ker T + \dim\ker T^t - \dim V\\
&= 2\dim V - \dim V\\
&= \dim V
\end{align}

by the rank-nullity theorem.

Hence we conclude

$$V = \operatorname{Im} T \,\dot+\, \operatorname{Im} T^t \,\dot+ \,H$$

Comment: $\operatorname{Im} T^t \,\dot+\, \ker T = V$ Why is it obvious?

Comment: @Beverlie It isn't. I proved it in the next two lines.

Comment: V=ImTt+˙kerT⊆kerTt+˙kerT Is oppsite side of inclusion trivial?

Comment: @Beverlie Yes. $\ker T \subseteq V$ and $\ker T^t \subseteq V$ implies $\ker T +\ker T^t \subseteq V$.

Comment: Do we need to assume " 0=Tx+Tty+z " at the first place?Isn't it superflous for logic? I think just taking arbitral element of $Tx+T^ty+z$ then applying $T$ would be sufficient

Comment: @Beverlie The sum $V_1 + V_2 + \cdots + V_n$ is direct if and only if $$x_1 + \cdots +x_n = 0 \text{ with } x_i \in V_i \implies x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0$$

Comment: So your approach of the proof of the first direct sum different from the second one? For the first you took the intersection to be trivial then check the dimension, but for the second one you used the above theorem.

Comment: @Beverlie Yes. The first direct sum can also be proved like this: assume $T^tx + y = 0$ for some $x \in V, y \in \ker T$. Apply $T$ to obtain $$0 = TT^tx + Ty = TT^tx$$
and now conclude $T^tx = 0$ like above. Then also $y = 0$. Therefore, the sum $\operatorname{Im} T^t + \ker T$ is direct. In both cases you still need to check dimensions to prove that the sum is equal to $V$.